# Toggle button is not working instead it is looking like regular checkbox using css

Tags: html, css, toggle

My toggle button is working if it run  in separate webpage where only toggle button included.
But its not working when i put up the same code in form  page where many css are included.

```css
/* Checkbox body */

#tog {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #E6E9EC;
}

#toggly {
  display: none;
}


/* The toggle */

.i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#tog:hover> .i {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  transform: scale(1.01);
}

#toggly:checked+ #tog > .i {
  margin-left: 24px;
}

#tog :active {
  background-color: #A6B9CB;
}

#tog :active> .i {
  width: 34px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

#toggly:checked+ #tog :active> .i {
  margin-left: 18px;
}

#toggly:checked+ #tog {
  background-color: #008FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The Toggle -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggly" >
  <label  for="toggly" id="tog"><div class="i"></div></label>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is working but if put in form page where many css included its not working.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Let me get this straight. The code you posted here is working, but it stops working as soon as you add some code that you haven't posted here?

Comment: When you are using this code with form elements, just add a parent class hierarchy to checkbox styling, so it wont get affected

Comment: Can you post the code including the form element that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Every thing looks fine except for this code below:

```
.i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

cause it might have been overridden so give it a parent id to make it more specific as below:

```
#tog .i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to you sir